# How to change data name in ggplotly?

Tags: r, graph, plotly, ggplotly

If you move the cursor, data is generated, but I want to change the data name.
ex) The x-axis name of the original ggplot is a and the y-axis is b.
I changed the name of the axis to xlab and ylab.
Afterwards, an interactive graph was drawn using ggplotly, and the data from the cursor came out as the name of the original axis. It means a and b.
Is there another option to rename ggplotly?

Comment: Please share some code and data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: add `layout(xaxis = list(title = "new x-axis title"), yaxis = list(title = "new name for the y-axis"))`